# How to align a plus next to an h3 tag

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a plus sign that should be positioned next to an h3 tag, so far the plus sign stays above the h3 and it is quite annoying. I tried applying margin and padding top, line-height but it still does not align. How can I align them both on the same line? I am talking about this line here:  `<h3 class="second-section-right-part-h3"><span class="plus alt"></span> Sub-Affiliation</h3>`

here is my html
`

```css
* {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

.nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
}

.header {
  height: 8%;
}

.nav-h1 {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 27px;
  font-size: 40px;
}

a {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px;
  font-family: 'Segoe UI', sans-serif;
  font-family: SegoeUI;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.a-container {
  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-top: 27px;
}

.footer {
  background-color: #e8e8e8;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
}

.alignleft {
  margin-left: 8%;
  font-family: SegoeUI;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 900;
  color: #000000;
}

.alignright {
  margin-right: 8%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.logo-section {
  margin-top: 1.3%;
  margin-left: 2%;
}

.logo-img {
  padding: 6px;
}

.first-section {
  width: 100%;
  background-image: url("/assets/images/first-image.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  position: relative;
}

.first-section-p {
  width: 400px;
  height: 314px;
  margin-left: 10%;
  padding-top: 10%;
  font-family: SegoeUI;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 4vh;
  font-weight: 900;
  text-align: center;
  color: #262262;
}

.small-button {
  width: 331px;
  height: 92px;
  margin-left: 12%;
  background-color: #e7af17;
  font-family: SegoeUI;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 900;
  color: white;
  border: none;
}

.second-section-text {
  color: #e8e8e8;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 70px;
  line-height: 0.7;
  font-family: SegoeUI;
  margin-left: 12%;
}

.content {
  min-height: 100%;
}

@media (min-width: 1281px) {
  .first-section {
    width: 100%;
    height: 800px;
    background-image: url("/assets/images/first-image.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
  }
  .small-button {
    width: 331px;
    height: 92px;
    margin-top: 8%;
    margin-left: 12%;
    background-color: #e7af17;
    font-family: SegoeUI;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 900;
    color: white;
    border: none;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 940px) {
  .small-button {
    width: 331px;
    height: 92px;
    margin-top: 8%;
    margin-left: 12%;
    background-color: #e7af17;
    font-family: SegoeUI;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 900;
    color: white;
    border: none;
  }
}

.second-section {
  margin-top: 100px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.third-section {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  margin-top: 100px;
  background-color: #e8e8e8;
}

.third-section-right-part {
  margin-left: 50px;
  margin-top: 5%;
}

.third-section-right-part-img {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
}

.third-section-left-part {
  width: 20%;
  margin-top: 3%;
}

.forth-section {
  height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.info-box {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  width: 70%;
  background-color: #e7af17;
}

.info-box-content {
  text-align: center;
}

button {
  width: 330px;
  height: 65px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #262262;
  border: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.info-box-content-h1 {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: SegoeUI;
  font-size: 60px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.info-box-content-p {
  font-family: SegoeUI;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-stretch: normal;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.message {
  width: 60%;
  margin-left: 10%;
}

.second-section-right-part {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-left: 30%;
}

.second-section-right-part-h3 {
  margin-top: 30px;
  color: #262262;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.second-section-right-part-p {
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.plus {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: linear-gradient(#fff, #fff), linear-gradient(#fff, #fff), #000;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: 50% 2px, 2px 50%;
  /*thickness = 2px, length = 50% (25px)*/
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.alt {
  background: linear-gradient(#000, #000), linear-gradient(#000, #000);
  background-position: center;
  background-size: 50% 2px, 2px 50%;
  /*thickness = 2px, length = 50% (25px)*/
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-container">
  <div class="headers">
    <div class="nav">
      <h1 class="nav-h1">Logo</h1>
      <div class="a-container">
        <a>About</a>
        <a>Vision</a>
        <a>Solutions</a>
        <a>Technology</a>
        <a>Contact</a>
      </div>
      <div class="logo-section">
        <img class="logo-img" src="/assets/images/facebook.png" alt="facebook logo">
        <img class="logo-img" src="/assets/images/linkedin.png" alt="linkedin logo">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="content-inside">
      <div class="first-section">
        <p class="first-section-p">Turnkey platforms <br> for businesses looking to rule the online market
          <button class="small-button">LEARN MORE</button>
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="second-section">
        <!-- <div class="second-section-paragraphs">
                        <p class="second-section-text">WHAT</p>
                        <p class="second-section-text">WHE DO</p>
                        <p class="second-section-text">BEST</p>
                    </div> -->
        <div class="second-section-right-part">
          <section class="second-section-right-part">
            <div>
              <h3 class="second-section-right-part-h3">Social Media</h3>
              <p class="second-section-right-part-p">Social Media Offering a 360 degree solution to generating exposure via Social Media Marketing. Using both ATL and BTL strategies in large social networks such as Facebook and Linkedin but also in small networks when seeking a specific demographic
                target.</p>
            </div>
          </section>
          <section class="second-section-right-part">
            <div>
              <h3 class="second-section-right-part-h3"><span class="plus alt"></span> Sub-Affiliation</h3>
              <p class="second-section-right-part-p">Sub-Affiliation Genuinely strengthen your brand and jump start traffic with an affiliate program. Link with a large scale business led supply chain, monitor activity and generate returns through an exponentially growing platform.
              </p>
            </div>
          </section>
          <section class="second-section-right-part">
            <div>
              <h3 class="second-section-right-part-h3">Mobile Adds</h3>
              <p class="second-section-right-part-p">Mobile Adds A multi-channeled platform tailor made for the mobile environment allowing ease of access, real time delivery and results driven optimization solutions allowing for cost efficient lead capture.</p>
            </div>
          </section>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="third-section">
        <div class="third-section-left-part">
          <h4 class="second-se">Leading The Way</h4>
          <br>
          <p> Dark Side management is a dynamic Online Media Powerhouse fueled with passion for developing and growing online businesses into world renowned enterprises. Putting a strong accent on online marketing solutions, Vici is one step ahead of the
            game with superior data management systems and prompt on key response time.<br><br> Streamlined by future oriented workflow methodology, Vici are a resilient group of focused and dedicated specialists that have a profound understanding of
            their duties and priorities.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="third-section-right-part">
          <section>
            <img src="/assets/images/cospace.png" alt="" class="third-section-right-part-img">
          </section>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="forth-section">
        <div class="info-box">
          <div class="info-box-content">
            <h1 class="info-box-content-h1">The Mission is Simple</h1>
            <p class="info-box-content-p">
              To Strategically Drive The Online Community Forward, Through A Wide Spectrum Integrating Market Intelligence And Experience Throughout, By Offering Unparalleled Resources And A True Understanding Of The Client’s Arena. </p>

            <br>
            <button>Contact Us </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
    <div class="nav">
      <h5 class="nav-h1">Logo</h5>
      <div class="a-container">
        <a>About</a>
        <a>Vision</a>
        <a>Solutions</a>
        <a>Technology</a>
        <a>Contact</a>
      </div>
      <div class="logo-section">
        <img class="logo-img" src="/assets/images/facebook.png" alt="facebook logo">
        <img class="logo-img" src="/assets/images/linkedin.png" alt="linkedin logo">
      </div>
    </div>
    <p class="message">*Please read the Privacy Policy and Terms & Conditions before continuing. <br> Use of our Services and Brokers websites is at your own risk. Information on our Website, applications and any marketing or email marketing material is strictly for information
      purposes and should not be construed as professional advice nor as an offer to engage in online trading, which may result in substantial or complete loss of funds.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: please show only the code necessary for your issue, not the entire code....

Comment: If you want to position icon next to h3 tag, why have you placed it before text inside h3 tag?

Answer (score 0):

Add this to .plus

```
position: relative;
top:20px;
```

Answer (score 0):

Make `second-section-right-part-h3` a flexbox with `align-items: center`:

```
.second-section-right-part-h3 {
  margin-top: 30px;
  color: #262262;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Ideally, however, you would probably want to keep the `span` and `h3` separate and use a new parent div on both of them to do the aligning.